# GeoServer SLD contours fail to draw some times when panning (using Layer Preview)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, contour

I am using GeoServer 2.13.2 with netcdf data from ECMWF and all is working fairly well with a fixed extent. As soon as I turn on Map Wrapping (wrapx) in OpenLayers (5.x) then contours, wind barbs, and wind arrows do not wrap. They seem stuck in the source data extent. 
Please note the following settings in GeoServer:

[image]

Please note that Layer Preview contours wrap fine on GeoServer so now I know it is setting on client side, but I can't see any difference in my WMS vs their preview. See image of preview:

[image]

On second thought the Layer Preview is not working fine. If I pan left then Contour rendering starts to have issues so it has to be on GeoServer side:
[image]

Why is it working some times and not others based on panning? In fact it gets worse the further you pan left or right. I don't know if it is issue in GeoServer or OpenLayers. See image when I pan further right:
[image]

How do I solve it?

Sample picture attached.
[image]

Comment: Vector Tiles for raster data? Doesn't make sense. Furthermore, on OpenLayers wrapx works well for BingMaps and is not available for ImageLayer/ImageWMS although as can be seen in the image above it does work as it seems to be extent related. The only thing that does not wrap are the contours.

Comment: I'm not sure that the "advanced projection handling" machinery works with rendering transformations, it might well not (haven't checked the code, but going by memory, it does not).

Comment: Hi @AndreaAime, if you look at my included pictures you can see that it works for a little while with wrapping, but starts to have problems the more it is panned. Seems more like a bug. Why would it work partly and then stop?

Comment: No idea... you're in untested waters, we use a lot RT but often on local area datasets.

Comment: Hi @AndreaAime, In further testing this just seems to be a wrapping issue. The source (ECMWF) data range is from 0-359 lon. Things like gradients work fine, but rendering with contours, arrows, wind barbs do not wrap. So if a range like 20-379 is sent then rendering only in source data range occurs. This seems like a huge bug. Is there a work around? Why would rendering work for gradients and not the other types? Seems like the same base code for wrapping.  Our app is for large marine vessels and the users will spend most of their time at a world view. I need some kind of work around for this.

Comment: Best approach is to code a fix or have someone develop it for you, http://geoserver.org/support/

Comment: @AndreaAime, Your contact page link is broken. Please PM me on cost of starter and basic plans.

Comment: I don't work the commercial side of things, just a techy. You can inquire here: https://www.geo-solutions.it/contacts/

Comment: And also fixed the link on the website, thanks for reporting!

Comment: I see that it is still not fixed in 2.15.0. That is too bad as Geoserver is in general a very nice map server. It seems that the ncWMS guys have solved this problem. Maybe you can get together with them on the rendering to solve it.